# How do I import something with rollup

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm successfully using rollup with `riot-mixin-pack` by using this line at the top of my code:

```
import { domEvent, parentScope } from 'riot-mixin-pack'
```

When rolled up the `domEvent` and `parentScope` objects are included at the top of my file.

I would like to import [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) with one or two supported languages input my rolled up file but I can't seem to figure out the `import` line I would need.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Rollup only knows how to import ES modules (i.e. modules that have `import` and `export` statements of their own). Highlight is a CommonJS module rather than an ES module, so you'll need to use a plugin in order to import it – specifically, [rollup-plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) alongside [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve).

Comment: I think the problem is not 'how to include it somehow' like `import hljs from "highlight.js"`, but 'how to include it with only 2 supported languages'. Otherwise you end up with a 1MB bundle with all languages. So far my best attempt at that is to download a build manually and load that via your very helpful `rollup-plugin-legacy`. But that requires manual interaction every time you want to update highlight.js :-/ Btw. thanks for building rollup, it's our future :-)